# How to control KDE (4.9.0) plasma widgets from command line?

Tags: kde4, widgets, plasma

I cannot delete "Window Menubar" widget from panel and "Facebook" widget from "Search and Launch" desktop bottom. And I don't want to delete all my settings, can I delete these widgets somewhere in config files or with some commands?

Comment: Looks like it's in `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`, checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are stored in `~/.kde/share/config/plasma-desktop-appletsrc`.

1. Edit it.
2. Don't change anything from GUI to prevent rewriting the file.
3. Log out.
4. Log in.

If you want to reset **all applets** state to "factory" settings just delete the file in the step 1.